# Rejecting non SSL/TLS connections with postfix

Tags: postfix

I'm aware of the configuration **setting smtpd_tls_security_level** where **encrypt** requires incoming smtpd connections to be done over SSL/TLS, and **may** is merely a preference for secure connections.

What I would like to know is:

- in the case of strict encryption (ie, **smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt**), and the server making the incoming connection does not support SSL/TLS, is there a way of emailing the rejected email's sender to advise of the reason for the failure?
- in the case of **smtpd_tls_security_level = may**, is there a way of identifying the type of incoming connection (ie, SSL/TLS or plaintext). It would be especially helpful if this information could be sent through to a handler-script for email-piping

Notes... I'm using:

- Centos
- Postfix
- Plesk (probably not relevant)
- Email-piping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your Postfix will reject the incoming connection and generate an SMTP error which should result in that error message being returned to the original sender. Typically SMTP errors are plain text limiting how much a non-technical sender will understand/learn from them though.
**NB** In [the manual](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html) that option is firmly discouraged:

> You can ENFORCE the use of TLS, so that the Postfix SMTP server announces STARTTLS and accepts no mail without TLS encryption, by setting `smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt`. According to RFC 2487 this MUST NOT be applied in case of a publicly-referenced Postfix SMTP server. This option is off by default and should only seldom be used.

Anecdotal evidence seems to indicate that it does help against spam, but I haven't seen numbers on how many common domains still don't support TLS and thus how much real mail will be rejected.

I don't have a Postfix deployment at hand but I would expect that your SMTP headers already provide information about whether or not the incoming connection was over SSL/TLS like sendmail does e.g.

```
Received: from mail.example.org (mail.example.org[192.168.0.1])
    by example.com (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id s96Md0B2019727
    (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 bits=256 verify=FAIL)
    for <address@example.com>; Tue, 7 Oct 2014 00:39:06 +0200
```

**Edit:**
Getting that information recorded in Postfix requires setting [`smtpd_tls_received_header = yes`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_received_header) in the `main.cf` configuration file and will result in a similar header:

```
Received: from host.example.com (host.example.com [192.168.0.2])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher cipher-name
    (actual-key-size/raw-key-size bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
```

Only the header information by your own mail infrastructure (the end-point) should be considered trusted, other headers can be modified in transit.

Comment: Hmmm... ok. So I guess discerning the type of incoming connection will take some fiddling with regular expressions.  I take the following line to mean that this particular email was delivered over a non-secure connection (ie, via HTTP) "Received: from [x.xxx.xx.xxx] by web121006.mail.ne1.yahoo.com via HTTP" ?

Comment: AFAIK postfix doesn't speak HTTP... And it is even more unlikely that you receive incoming e-mail over HTTP and not SMTP. That seems more like a header webmail would add, or would be added for a client that sent the message using an [API](https://developer.yahoo.com/mail/) and should probably not be seen as an indication of TLS usage.  You should focus on the header that gets added by your Postfix server. That may require setting [`smtpd_tls_received_header = yes`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_received_header)

Answer (score 2):

If you have smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt, and the server sending the mail can't negotiate TLS session, then it's the sending server's responsibility to notify the sender with a non delivery report email. A server that wouldnt do that is just terribly broken. It is not possible to do it on the recipient's server as SSL/TLS failure happens before you even know the sender or recipient of the email.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks for the insight. +1